# tsc --module always generates the same output no matter the argument

Tags: typescript, compiler-services

I'm pretty new to Javascript, NodeJS and --obviously-- TypeScript. I'd like to experiment with the compiler services in `src/services` (Windows) to provide intellisense, etc. for an editor.

As far as I can tell, I need to be able to `require` the TypeScript services code in a NodeJS server and communicate with that from the editor. I couldn't find any NodeJS-specific TypeScript services code, so I think I'd have to compile the services code with `--module amd` to make it available to NodeJS via RequireJS.

If the above is correct, my attempts to compile the services code with `--module amd` yield exactly the same results as using the default module kind (see below).

```
$ tsc.cmd --module amd --out amd.js .\languageService.ts
$ tsc.cmd --out comm.js .\languageService.ts
$ diff.exe .\amd.js .\comm.js
$
```

Comment: I created a video tutorial on internal vs. external modules to clarify confusions : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: If your goal is editor support for TS, check out [typescript-tools](https://github.com/clausreinke/typescript-tools)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is admittedly confusing, but the code in languageService.ts isn't in a 'module' in the sense of AMD/RequireJS's definition of 'module'.

The spec refers to things inside a `module` block as "internal modules". That's what you're seeing in languageService.ts. You can think of them more like containers or singletons that expose a top-level name (looking at the code gen for a simple internal module clarifies this quite a bit). You consume these like regular top-level objects without any module loader at all.

Producing *external* modules (as named by the spec) for `require` is done by putting the `export` directive on a top-level declaration in a .ts file (see spec section 9.2.1). There are some samples (e.g. imageboard) available for download that do this if you're interested.

Comment: Just going to language-lawyer myself: Internal modules introduce a name in their parent scope, not at the top-level.

Comment: related TS issues: https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/521 https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/534 https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/97

Answer (score 1):

You have to have your modules defined as `export module`, not your `module` and then compile it with `--m amd` or `--module amd`.

Took me few hours to realize :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. BTW, it looks like you're looking for the backticks instead of the single quotes.